# Play 2.1.1: Use Logback Evaluators in application-logger.xml

Tags: logging, logback, playframework-2.1, scala-2.10

I am using in Play 2.1.1 for my project a custom logging configuration. Therefor I created a application-logger.xml in the conf directory. This works like a charm.

Now I wanted to add a logback evaluator (based on the official doc: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Evaluators) to the logging configuration file to output the %caller information only in specific cases:

```
<configuration>

<evaluator name="DISP_CALLER_EVAL">
    <expression>logger.contains("a specific string")</expression>
</evaluator>

<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date - [%level] - %logger in %thread in caller: %caller{3, DISP_CALLER_EVAL}
            %message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="play" level="INFO" />
<logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

However, if I start the play server after adding the evaluator snippet to the log configuration, no logging happens at all and the server doesn't execute the code at all. It looks that the server crashed.

Has anyone an working example of a logging configuration with an evaluator rule on Play 2.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<evaluator name="DISP_CALLER_EVAL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator">
    <expression>logger.contains("a specific string")</expression>
</evaluator>
```